# Spring - Neo4j : Class Attribute return Null when there is Relationship Entity

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have 3 classes created on my Spring Project. Class A, B and C. Class A and C is Independent Node. Class B is RelationshipEntity of Class A-C.

```
@NodeEntity
public class A {
    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;

    private String id;

    @Relationship(type = "a_has_c", direction = "INCOMING")
    private C cData;

    public A() {
        super();
    }
}

@RelationshipEntity(type="a_has_c")
public class B {
    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;

    private String id;

    @StartNode
    private A a;

    @EndNode
    private C c;

    public B() {
        super();
    }
}

@NodeEntity
public class C {
    @GraphId
    private Long graphId;

    private String id;

    public C() {
        super();
    }
}
```

The problem is, before I create `@RelationshipEntity` Node, I can retrieve information of `cData` from attribute on Class A. But after I have created `@RelationshipEntity`, it always return Null.

Do I need to always fetch 2 times if I want to get information of `cData` from attribute at class A?

I am using `Spring Boot 1.5.6 Release` and `Neo4j Community 3.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

The relationship definition in class `A`

```
@Relationship(type = "a_has_c", direction = "INCOMING")
private C cData;
```

should be

```
@Relationship(type = "a_has_c", direction = "INCOMING")
private B cData;
```

But this will also give you `null` for the `C c` in the relationship entity `B` because Spring Data Neo4j / Neo4j Object Graph Mapper will load with a depth of **1**. This value means load the node in question and look "one step" in the relationships. If it is a `NodeEntity` load this, if it is a `RelationshipEntity` load just this and do not go further in this case.

This is also written in the documentation in this section after the code samples: https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/2.1/reference/#reference:annotating-entities:relationship

Comment: Is there any other ways to get information of cData from Class C as attribute of Class A? Right now, I always do 2 queries, for getting Entity A, and then match entity A at Relationship Entity B and fill the Transient attribute (new) at Entity A. But I think it is bad workaround, because I need to run 2 queries just to get cData.

Comment: I do not know how you fetch the data but there is support to change the default load depth *1*. For example: `session.loadAll(A.class,2)` where 2 is the custom depth.